# Replacement for Firefox extension Firebug

Tags: firefox, php-curl

I have not coded in a while and apparently the Firefox extension Firebug has been disabled as they want you to use their developer tools. I used to use Firebug for PHP cUrl, as when I clicked submit on a form it would show me where the form submit would go to and the post or get data that was submitted in real time. Is there a current alternative to this or can someone let me know where in the developer tools of Firefox or Chrome that I can do the same thing. I see a console but there is no option to make it persistent through redirects.

Comment: Both the Network and Console tabs in the DevTools have "Persist Logs" checkboxes. Are you not seeing those?

Comment: I see it now, thank you. Should have looked harder